Unresolved reference: io
I want to create a Flutter plugin for Android. Gradle builds correctly, but the packages are not installed, and I receive an error. Below is the image showing the error. The issue seems to be related to unresolved dependencies or incorrect Gradle configurations. I've already tried cleaning the project and syncing Gradle files, but it didn't help. I'm using Gradle version 8.7 and Kotlin version 1.7.10.
Could this be an issue with my build.gradle file or my project setup? What steps can I take to troubleshoot this and ensure the packages are correctly installed?

